# read data from chart, ms as x value

Tags: charts

i have some trouble with adding pinots to a chart and read them back to an array.

with tis code iam adding a new piont to my chart, y_value is a normal double var
time_stamp is a string with the current daytime (15:56:45:799) with millisecounds

```
string time_stamp = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();

chart_logger.Series[0].Points.AddXY(time_stamp, y_value);
```

after plotting the chart i want to save alle datapionts in an txt file, so i want the read all points form the chart
i tried it with

```
DataPoint[] asd = chart_logger.Series[0].Points.ToArray();
```

it read all the y values from the chart but i the x values are always zero
does someone have any idea

thanks for the help

Ralf

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ToOADate()' and 'FromOADate(double d)'.

```
chart_logger.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart_logger.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
chart_logger.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), y_value);

DataPoint[] asd = chart_logger.Series[0].Points.ToArray();
var x = DateTime.FromOADate(asd[0].XValue);
```

Or

```
chart_logger.Series[0].YValuesPerPoint = 2;
var time = DateTime.Now;
string time_stamp = time.ToLongTimeString() + ":" + time.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
chart_logger.Series[0].Points.AddXY(time_stamp, y_value, time.ToOADate());

DataPoint[] asd = chart_logger.Series[0].Points.ToArray();
var x = DateTime.FromOADate(asd[0].YValues[1]);
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

i set the x value type to Time and the code you posted works but the problem is that there are no millisecounds in the chart, so when i add 2 points in the same secound it look wrong